# C++ non-static function pointer inside own class

Tags: c++, c++11, timer, static, function-pointers

I am writing my own timer in c++. I was wondering whether it is possible to pass a function to the timer constructor and call this function later.

I was thinking about using function pointers for this, however I can't find a solution for passing a non-static function inside the class itself.

G++ gives me this error:

> Server.cpp:61:54: error: invalid use of non-static member function
>          serverTimer = new timer::Timer(onTimerTick,3000);

My class Server.cpp looks like this:

```
    private:
    void onTimerTick(){
          //do something with class variables, so can't use static? :(
      }
      public:
      Server(int port) : socket(port)
      {
          serverTimer = new timer::Timer(onTimerTick,1000);
          serverTimer->start();
      }
```

This is timer.h:

```
#ifndef TIMER_H
#define TIMER_H
namespace timer {
    class Timer{
    public:
        Timer(void (*f) (void),int interval);
        std::thread* start();
        void stop();
    private:
        int interval;
        bool running;
        void (*f) (void);
    };
}
#endif
```

This is timer.cpp:

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include "timer.h"

timer::Timer::Timer(void (*f) (void),int interval){
    this->f = f;
    this->interval = interval;
}

std::thread* timer::Timer::start(){
    this->running = true;
    return new std::thread([this]()
    {
        while(this->running){
            this->f();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(this->interval));
        }
    });
    //return
}

void timer::Timer::stop(){
    this->running = false;
}
```

Is there a better solution for this problem, or is this the wrong syntax for passing my function?
Hope someone has a great solution for this.

Comment: Look up `std::function`.

Comment: What you kind of need are ``delegates``. Just search stack overflow for c++ and delegates and you will find thousands of pages ;)

Comment: @BitTickler, delegate is a terrible word, which comes from language where *pointer* is banned, so that plain 'function pointer' can not be used.

Comment: Note that you should use `std::atomic<bool> running` and returning `std::thread*` is suspicious too.

Comment: @SergeyA Language is a funny thing, is it not? The term delegate in the context of C++ has special meaning. And there is more to it than just "function pointer". So, if it is used in other context with other meanings applies not much to how it is used in the context of c++.

Comment: Wow never had a reaction that quick. The solution was using std::function. Will look up all the hints too. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you specified a function pointer for a standalone function, but you are trying to bind it to a member function. (non-static) member functions really are different: they have a hidden this pointer that needs to be passed to them.

To solve this, one solution is to use std::function instead of a function pointer, and then pass the necessary code as a lambda.

So your function pointer becomes:

```
std::function<void (void)>;
```

and you could call it like this:

```
serverTimer = new timer::Timer([this]{onTimerTick ();},1000);
```

Comment: That was fast! And it works :) the lambda is [this]{onTimerTick();}

Comment: I personnaly prefer `std::bind` in simple cases.

Comment: Note: when you have a class that has a std::function object which embeds a this pointer to itself, it is a good idea to make that class non copyable, as the copy semantics are incorrect.